# How to pull 1 January 2021 stock price data with google finance

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

I'm trying to pull 1/1/2021 stock price data with google finance but it gives an error. I can do it for 2020 or any other time but not 2021. Please write if you know how to solve.

```
=index(GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL","close",DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,1)),2,2)
```

Comment: US markets were closed on January 1, 2021 for the New Year's Day holiday.  It looks like when you choose a date when markets were closed, you get the closing price of the following trading day.  Since there hasn't yet been a trading day since then, there's no price to get.  I expect it will work after the markets close on Monday, January 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can run:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL", "close", DATE(2020, 12, 1), TODAY())
```

and see that there is no value for your date as of right now

solution:

- wait a day or more
- grab it from an alternative source (yahoo finance)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, i will try to write a code like try, except in python. If it can't pull the data i will try to take one day before's data, will share the code here when its done.